# Open Semantic UI Calendar within a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui

I need to open [Semantic-UI-Calendar](https://github.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI-Calendar) within a loop but nothing works, which it should. The logic is, when I click `data-id="expensecal"`, it should give me the `id` which is `expense_date2` or `expense_date1` but instead it give me the `id` of the `input`:

**Rails View:**

```
#---Loop----#
<div class="required field">
  <label>Claim date</label>
  <div class="ui calendar" data-id="expensecal" id="expense_date<%= contract.id %>">
    <div class="ui input left icon">
      <i class="calendar icon"></i>
      <%= f.text_field :date, id: "expense_date_input", placeholder: "Expense date" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$( "[data-id=expensecal]" ).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let id = '#' + e.target.id;
  console.log(id); // Shows the field input id. Why?
  $(id).calendar({
    type: 'date'
  });
});
```

I use this method to open up a [semantic modal](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html) in a loop and it works ok but not sure why not with the calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize all the elements at page ready using a class, remove the click event

Try using the following code:

```
$('.ui.calendar').calendar({
    type: 'date'
  });
```

demo:https://jsbin.com/kenaqiyuqe/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: There will be more than on calendars on the page. It's a loop.

Comment: Ok that worked but I have to click the field twice and the calendar pops up twice. First click does nothing that's why I have to click twice.

Comment: strange why are you initializing the plugin on the click event?

Comment: Trying to grab the `contract.id` to select the correct `id`. But I think it must not be on a click event.

Comment: why do you want the id?

Comment: Ahhh! I had this before `$('#expense_date').calendar({...});` I was almost there lol. Thanks